# Meshes won't respond to ANY Transformation

Tags: mesh, objects, transforms, transform-orientation

I have reopened a blender file (Blender 2.93) that I worked on 2 months ago, and for some reason none of my meshes are responding to transformations (Scaling, moving or rotating) the axis seem to rotate but the meshes remain unaffected.

[image]

[image]
I have added an emission cube and tried rotating and scaling it and only the axis move (almost like they were emptys) I have attached some photos. I have set my options to apply transforms to affect origins and location, so I made sure I hadn't "Move Object Centers Only", but it seems to be alright?

[image]

I can't move any of my meshes or objects or lights, only the Axis, and I'm unsure how this happened? Disclaimer, I have just recently began with blender.

Comment: I would uncheck all the boxes in the Affect Only panel and see if that's good. Unless you're doing something specific and you know what you are doing I wouldn't advise checking any of these boxes.

Comment: I think all your items are locked in the Outliner-panel. Click on the Syphon-icon to view extra options for your items, check the arrow-icon, you can click on the arrow next to your item to (un)lock it.